# Custom module extension

Tags: module, magento2.2.6

I am trying to create a custom module in Magento2 2.2.6 but I am facing the following error.

```
Element 'add', attribute 'resource': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'bcode_Bapp::helloworld' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vendor name has to start with an uppercase letter, which the pattern tells you. Just head over to https://regex101.com/ and check the pattern against your string `bcode_Bapp::helloworld`.